# Combining Seq.tryFind and x.IsSome in one line

Tags: text, f#, find

I'm trying to read data associated with specific (optional) keywords from a file into an immutable in F#.

My code does what I want when the keyword exists in the file:

```
let variable1 = 
    lines 
    |> Seq.find(fun x -> x.Contains "keyword1") 
    |> fun x -> x.Split(']').[1]
```

When the keyword doesn't exist, `Seq.find` breaks as expected. Rather than having a few lines with tryFind and if/then I'm trying to make it all work in one line in F# fashion, but I don't know how to  process the output of tryFind as the subsequent split operation demands type string rather than the unknown type from IsSome. How do I satisfy the red squigglies demand further for type constraints?

```
let variable1 = 
    lines 
    |> Seq.tryFind(fun x -> x.Contains "keyword1") 
    |> fun x -> if x.IsSome then x.Split(']').[1]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do:

```
let variable1 = 
    lines 
    |> Seq.tryFind(fun x -> x.Contains "keyword1") 
    |>  fun x -> if x.IsSome then     x.Split(']').[1]
```

the last `x` has type `string option`.  I would do something like

```
let variable1 = 
    lines 
    |> Seq.tryFind(fun x -> x.Contains "keyword1") 
    |> function |Some(t) -> t.Split(']').[1] |None -> "" (*need a value for the None branch*)
```

Comment: `|> Option.map (...)` would fit here, making `variable1` a `string option` type and allowing the caller to deal with it from there.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to act on a single match, `Option.map` is the way to go, as mentioned by ildjarn

```
let variable1 = 
    lines 
    |> Seq.tryFind(fun x -> x.Contains "keyword1") 
    |> Option.map (fun x -> x.Split(']')
```

Alternatively, you can use map / choose if you want to act on **many** entries

```
let variables = 
    lines 
    |> Seq.map(fun x -> if x.Contains "keyword1" then Some x else None) 
    |> Seq.choose (fun x -> x.Split(']')
```

In any case, the return type of each branches `then` and `else` of a `if .. then .. else ...` expression need to have the ***same type***.

That **common** type of the two branches is the type of the ***whole*** expression `if .. then .. else ...`. This allows referential transparency where you can always plug a complex expression where a more simple one is accepted.

This is a great freedom which comes at a little cost : you have to actually give an expression in both branches, of the correct type.

The 'exception' is when you are in a computation expression with some zero defined, but even in this case, both branched are provided for, just not by you..

Comment: The Option.map copied in as above gives me red squigglies and the error message "Invalid Expression on left of assignment". The explanation of why both the if then branches need to be completed is helpful though, thankyou.

Comment: @arthuritus - There's a missing close-paren on the Option.map line in nicolas example code, but Option.map is still the best answer.